# WPF UserControl loading dynamically based on which button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I am very new to WPF and this is my 1st application.

I have a Ribbon with different buttons. I want to load a UserControl based on which button is clicked.

I have a button called "Change Password" and I created the UserControl that will represent the UI to change the password.

I have another button called "Unlock Account" and I have a UserControl that can unlock an account.

```
App --> Ribbon --> RibbonButton --> SwappableUserControlAtRunTime
```

I want to use the same space in my Window to load/unload UserControls based on whats clicked.

I am using WPF 4.5 and .Net 4.5 on Windows 8.1
I am targeting PC's with .Net 4.5 and Windows 7+

Comment: Are you primarily using the MVVM or Code Behind pattern?

Comment: you try my article here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30898.simple-navigation-technique-in-wpf-using-mvvm.aspx

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian nice article but its too complicated for a n00b to understand. I hope to one day revisit it

Answer (score 2):

You can load the UserControls in the ContentControl. Refer below code.

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="LayoutWPF_Learning.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Ribbon Grid.Row="0">
        <RibbonTab Header="Load UC">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="UserControl1" Click="Button_Click"/>
                <Button Content="UserControl2" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </RibbonTab>
    </Ribbon>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="cntCtrl" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

```
 public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cntCtrl.Content = new UserControl1();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cntCtrl.Content = new UserControl2();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. However each control is a different "size". Is there a way to "fit" it so it looks nice.

Comment: Edited my post to add grid to it. Now the content will fit to entire area

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're going with codebehind (I'd recommend you look into MVVM) you'll be able to use a Converter to do this, this is more the WPF way of working than altering controls at runtime from your C# code.

There'll be loads of examples of how to use converters; Google "WPF Converter".  Here's one that's relevant to your requirement: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/285358/All-purpose-Boolean-to-Visibility-Converter

Comment: isn't Code-Behind and MVVM the same? I am very new to WPF. So why would a converter help me?

Comment: No, MVVM (Model View View-Model) is a design pattern kind of like MVC (Model View Controller).  Take for example a CustomerEditor screen, the Model would be a Customer class (name, address, etc), your View is a window (i.e. XAML) and the ViewModel is a class that loosely ties them together.  WPF is designed to be used with MVVM - old/good article http://goo.gl/neIkr1
Converters allow you to control things like visibility easily.  For you, use a container (eg a Grid) to hold both UserControls and then control visibility with a Converter - allowing you to easily show one or other in same area