# Navigate to another wpf without opening new windows

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, navigationservice

I am new to WPF , i can't find a way to open a new WPF window on the same main WPF app
i tried Frame method , here is the code :-

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_FINAL.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_FINAL"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
        TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
        TextElement.FontSize="13"
        TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"
        TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
        Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
        Height="768"
        Width="1366"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        Title="MainWindow">

    <Grid Background="#dff9fb"
          Margin="33,10,-33,-10">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="13.5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="152" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"
                              MinWidth="335.5" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Frame Margin="0,0,0.5,10"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
               x:Name="main"
               Grid.RowSpan="6">

        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

cs code

```
            main.Content = new Window1();
```

but when i run it gives me break exception 
i tried also navigation service but i found it's only associated with Pages
any suggestion how to do this ?
thank you

Comment: No that's not the way to do it Ahmed ! You should use `UserControl` or `Pages` for this purpose

Comment: Look at this tut : https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/usercontrols-and-customcontrols/creating-using-a-usercontrol/

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952693/wpf-usercontrol-loading-dynamically-based-on-which-button-is-clicked

Comment: A `UserControl` is just like a `window` without frame (by default) ok and you can Instantiate and use it just like a window. But unlike Window you can Embed a `userControl` inside Window. Hope it helps :)

Comment: There's also the Popup control that creates a short term dialog that is completely UI based. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Frame` can host any content, even HTML.
The `Page` only exposes special helpers like the `NavigationService` to make navigation between pages more convenient.

A `Window` can not be the child of another element e.g. child of `Frame`. It must be the root element. By assigning the `Window` to `Frame.Content` the `Frame` beceomes the parent of the `Window`, which is illegal.

A simple solution would be to convert the `Window1` class to a `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl">
  <TextBlock Text="TEST CONTROL" FontSize="25"/>
</UserControl>
```

Now your assignment will work:

```
main.Content = new MyUserControl();
```

or

```
main.Navigate(new MyUserControl());
```

or

```
main.Navigate("file path to/MyUserControl.xaml");
```